# Simplify double minus signs

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am puzzled as to why `Simplify` won't remove "double minus signs" in certain expressions.

Here it does:

```
Simplify[-(-1 - c) a b]
```

> a b (1 + c)

Here it doesn't:

```
Simplify[-(-1 + c) a b]
```

> -a b (-1 + c)

How, in the second example, can I get `Simplify` to output `a b (1 - c)`?

Comment: That's because `Simplify` (mostly) minimizes the `LeafCount` of expressions. The `LeafCount` of those two is the same. See their `FullForm` to understand why.

Comment: Why not just enter `-(-1 + c) a b` without `Simplify` as the output is `a b (1 - c)`?

Comment: This was just a minimalistic example. I have longer expressions I need to simplify, but `Simplify` often outputs expressions of the form `-a b (-1 + c)` instead of `a b (1 - c)`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Any suggestions, then, how to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Simplify` tries different transformations and calculates `ComplexityFunction` of transformed expression after each try. Expression with minimal `ComplexityFunction` is returned.

By default, `Simplify` uses `ComplexityFunction` based on `LeafCount`,
but you can override this.

For example, you can add some penalty points for negative integers in the resulting expression. In this case simplify will try to avoid them.

```
f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Integer?Negative, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e];
Simplify[-(-1 + c) a b, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

> a b (1 - c)

You can tune `ComplexityFunction` to your needs by adding or subtracting points for different subexpressions.

Alternatively, you can define a `ComplexityFunction` based on a string length of resulting expression.

```
f[e_] := StringLength[ToString[InputForm[e]]];
Simplify[-(-1 + c) a b, ComplexityFunction -> f]
```

> a b (1 - c)

This will also make double minus signs less attractive for `Simplify`.

Default complexity function and more examples can be found in the documentation center for [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html).